# Parent prop cant watchable by child if prop is empty

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-reactivity

Currently building component sets for forms generated by json array with objects similar to below. I need to watch parent value object in order to populate and connect other fields to eachother.

```
{
  id: 'title',
  label: 'Title',
  type: 'text',
  placement: 'main',
  placeholder: 'Write Something...'
},
{
  id: 'slug',
  label: 'Slug',
  type: 'slug',
  placement: 'seo',
  populateFrom: 'title',
  gridSize: 6
}
```

There is a hierarchy to components lets parent (or grandparent) know field values as form model.

```
FormView
  Field
    FieldText
  Field
    FieldSlug
```

populateFrom property checked by FieldSlug for populating data from selected model property, in this case its "title" field.

```
// this.field is field definition object sampled above
// $emit('input') notifies FormView to change value for form

if (this.field.populateFrom) {
  this.populateFrom = this.$parent.$watch('value', (after, before) => {
    this.$emit('input', slug(after[this.field.populateFrom]))
  }, {deep: true})
}
```

---

For edit and create forms, i'm using the same view (component). Data fetched from Vuex and filtered by getters. When its create mode, getters cant find any object from state and returns empty object.

If its empty object, $parent.value can not be watchable. (nothing triggered) If it returns object from state, it works perfectly well.

afaik, **$set makes objects reactive automatically**; thats what i use inside "FormView" to set data. **Data successfully set, but nothing triggered by $watch**.

What i'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

- used $data object as a new
- used $set to setup every key in form

it solved reactivity issue.